# Laravel view routing

Tags: laravel-5.4

I created a laravel project and I added to the resources/views : 2 blades,

`home.blade.php`
`restaurants.blade.php`

In laravel 5.4, I created a route in web.php

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('home');
});
Route::get('restaurants', function () {
    return view('restaurants');
});
```

when I open my project localhost/food/public
the home blade is opening.
When I click on restaurants, the URL changes to : `localhost/food/public/restaurants` and giving me :

```
Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.

1/1
NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 179:
```

screenshot routes listing:[image]

screenshot views folder:
[image]

htaccess :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: see routes listing `php artisan route:list` and check if your page is there or not.

Comment: i checked route listing, the page is appearing, I checked the page in resources views, It's there

Answer (score 0):

Your image is showing that your project is in **htdocs/bitfood**, and you are assuming **htdocs/food** instead.

So try open:

> http://localhost/bitfood/public/restaurants

If the page does not load correctly then try open:

> http://localhost/bitfood/public/index.php/restaurants

..in order to check if the problem could be raised from `.htaccess` cause it could not be read.

Comment: http://localhost/bitfood/public/index.php/restaurants is working but without css, the first link giving me the error, and about bitfood and food, it's a mistake here, my project is bitfood and all is ok. any help?

Comment: any help or solution ?

Comment: Attach your `.htaccess` to your question

Comment: i added the htcaccess, sorry for late replies maybe timezone issue,

Answer (score 0):

Copy .htaccess file from public folder to root folder and try again.
It will remove the public/index.php from your URL.
     Then try this URL

```
 localhost:8000/bitfood/restaurants
```